# When in a problem must we proof that an action is well defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Here is a question:

[image]

And here is its answer:

[image]

[image]

In the answer of (b), why he did not prove that the action is well defined? and how can we prove that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe he should have, but my guess is it seemed obvious to him so he didn't mention it : what you can do is define the "natural action" of $R$ on $A/IA$, and shows that it goes to the quotient $R/I$

Comment: Could you please explain it in detail as it is not clear for me ?@Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is an $R$-module, $I$ a two-sided ideal in $R$, then $A/IA$ is an $R$-module with the induced action : $r\cdot (x+ IA) = r\cdot x + IA$.

This is well-defined as if $x\equiv y$ mod $IA$, then $x-y \in IA$ and so $r\cdot (x-y) \in IA$ ($I$ is an ideal), so $r\cdot x \equiv r\cdot y$ mod $IA$.

Now with this induced action, if $r\in I$, and $x\in A/IA$, then $r\cdot (x+ IA) = IA = \overline{0}$.

Therefore the morphism $R\to \mathrm{End}(A/IA)$ ($r\mapsto (x\mapsto r\cdot x)$) factorizes through $R/I$ : there is a natural action of $R/I$ over $A/IA$, which makes $A/IA$ into a $R/I$-module.

All of this is pretty standard, and I assume the author didn't go through the trouble of proving that the action is well defined (although this is quite surprising as he/she did go through the trouble of proving that it's an action)

**Note** : I assumed you knew that an action of $R$ on $A$ is the same as a ring morphism $R\to \mathrm{End}(A)$ (ring of group endomorphisms )

Comment: Frankly speaking what you wrote is not clear for me ....... could you explain it inthe simplest way please?

Comment: What parts are not clear ? (So I know what to add)